# How can I deploy a django appserver as an egg, running behind fastcgi?

Tags: django, fastcgi, setuptools, egg

I want to run a django appserver behind apache/fastcgi.  That's no problem, django does that out of the box.

I want this appserver to be deployable via setuptools.  That is, I will make it as an egg and install it with easy_install.  And that part I can also handle, even though setuptools is not a standard complement to a django appserver.

But what I can't figure out is how the dispatch.fcgi would actually call into this my_app.egg to "start" the server process.  Has anyone ever run in this config before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want to do instead is use something like [Paste](http://pythonpaste.org/) to delegate to your egg (see example Paste deployment config file [here](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/#the-config-file)); this means doing the `flup` stuff (which translates FastCGI to WSGI) manually since you'll be pointing `flup` at Paste instead of at Django, but you can look at the Django management script to find out how it works.